# How to play audio file after receiving call in linphone when zrtp encryption is enabled in iOS?

Tags: ios, encryption, linphone

I am re-skinning linphone and want to add an extra functionality like: I want to play an audio file when someone is receiving an ZRTP Encrypted call in linphone.

There is a method in linphone name "core_play_local...." which plays the audio file. Now I am able to play the audio file by calling the function "core_play_local" from "LinphoneManager" Class but now all I need is detect the call, is it encrypted or not?

Comment: I have solved this problem if anyone needs please let me know.

Comment: Would you consider adding a full answer below? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, @MdRashedNizam! I'd love to know how you managed to do it.

Comment: Sorry @halfer,gabriel_vincent , I lost my mac and all my resource has gone.